# Ensure clause in Eiffel

Tags: eiffel

I'm doing an assignment in Eiffel and I'm having trouble implementing my ensure clause. Is there some special syntax you need to include a variable or function?

This is my code at the moment for my 'put' function

```
    put(key: K; value: V)
    require

            key /= void
    local
        tmp:ITEM[K,V]
    do

        create tmp.make(key, value)
        list.put_front (tmp)
        count := count + 1
    ensure

    count = old count + 1 and list.has(key, value)
    end
```

This is the code for the 'has' function

```
    has(key:K; val:V):BOOLEAN
require
    key /= void
local

    flag: INTEGER
    do

    flag := 0
    from
        list.start
    until
        list.exhausted
    loop
        if list.item.getkey = key then
            if list.item.getvalue = val then
                flag := 1
            end
        end
        list.forth
    end
    if flag = 1 then
        Result := true
    else
        Result := false
    end
    ensure
        --???   
end
```

The assignment is to implement a map adt via linked list. The 'put' function inserts item(key, value) into the list. The 'has' function checks whether the list contains (key value) pair.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact problem? Is it a compilation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be just

```
Result = across list as c some (c.item.key = key and c.item.value = value) end
```

But then there are several other comments on the code:

1. I do not see where the property `key /= Void` is used. So it looks like it is not required.
2. Given that the code of `put` inserts elements of type `ITEM`, the postcondition of `put` should also use `across list ... end` instead of `list.has (key, value)`. So I suspect it should be just `has (key, value)` without `list.` in front of it.
3. I do not see any point of using an auxiliary variable `flag`. The reserved variable `Result` will do just fine.
4. All variables in Eiffel are initialized by the default values, so there is no need to assign `0` to `flag` (or `false` to `Result` in a simplified version) at the beginning of a routine.
5. Usually there is no need to have dedicated getters in Eiffel, so normally the code `list.item.getkey` looks like `list.item.key`.
6. One can preemptively exit from the loop by calling `list.finish` that moves cursor to the last item of the list when a required element is found. Then after `list.forth` the loop exit condition is satisfied and the loop terminates.

Comment: thanks, it worked. As for the list.item.getkey, item is another class and getkey was a method in item